# Php file_get_contents and curl_exec dont work with external files

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

When i use file_get_contents  or  curl_exec with an url (http://google.com or other) return false with different context, user_agent, etc... No errors no Warnings

With local files it works, example:  `file_get_contents("a.txt");`

**Configuration:**

Php.ini is right: *allow_url_fopen = On*

No Firewall: *sudo ufw status: inactive*

**Phpinfo():**

Protocols:  dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp

Host:   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

SSL: Version    OpenSSL/1.0.1e

OpenSSL: support    enabled

OpenSSL: Library Version    OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

OpenSSL: Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

It is a dedicated server, maybe is there a physical firewall? or something I can't control?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try adding a `context` argument to `file_get_contents` that includes the `useragent` - similarly with your curl request

Comment: let us know what is the error?

Comment: Yes i tried. user_agent different context. curl_exec  doesn't work neither

Comment: No errors, No warnings, as i said it works with local file

Comment: you mention google but is that the actual url you tried or is there a specific one for which your calls are failing?

Comment: Does it work if you try to access `http://your.hostname/resource/`  something you can control access to so you can make sure it's not a headers issue.

Comment: run this code in your server & check php log.It must return something

Comment: (http://google.com or other)  all the urls fail

Comment: Does running `wget` or `curl` on the command line of that server work?

Comment: tested with local url too, as http://your.hostname/resource/ and it works

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your comments:

> Does running wget or curl on the command line of that server work? –
>   apokryfos

Exactly was a server error not a php issue, i just use the easy way to fix it:

After some minutes trying to find something wrong with resolv.conf,head,.d

**Just use this solution if you didn't modify nothing manually and you don't have a customized resolv**

.I've removed resolvconf:

```
aptitude purge resolvconf
```

And i installed it again:

```
apt-get install resolconf
```